# Adding a class with a different z-index

Tags: css, z-index

I have a site with multiple pages. I have created a footer so I want to include that to all of the pages:

```
<footer class="footer-section">
        <div class="footer-wrap">
            <p> ©2017 ... </p>
            <p> ... </p>
        </div>
</footer>
```

In one of the pages, I want to change the footer's color and z-index, so an element can be above it.

```
<footer class="footer-section sale-footer">
        <div class="footer-wrap">
            <p> ©2017 ... </p>
            <p> ... </p>
        </div>
</footer>
```

So how should I proceed about that? If I add a class to it, and give that class a z-index, that doesn't work. Is this something only doable with Javascript?

Footer scss:

```
.footer-section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 416px;
    background: $pinkish-tan;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.footer-wrap{
    @include flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 10px 30px 50px;
    color: white;
    a{
        color: white !important;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}
```

Form on top of the footer:

```
.vende-form{
  width: 771px;
  height: 1795px;
  background-color: #5c555a;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 20px rgba(44, 40, 44, 0.1);
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -30px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding-left: 72px;
  padding-top: 63px;
}

.vende-form-header{
    font-family: HKExplorerSoft-Bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.28;
    letter-spacing: 0.6px;
    color: $dark-salmon;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the other element's z-index higher?

Comment: I did, it's just not working?

Comment: Does your footer have a `position` property set? e.g. `position: fixed`

Comment: A display: flex with justify-content: flex-end;

Comment: Can you give an example of what you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Can you try putting `position: relative;` on the other element - assuming it's a div.

Comment: http://codepen.io/masterdoctor/pen/VpJqyg

Comment: Question: is the form meant to be inside the footer? if so - just put the tag in the footer.

Comment: No not inside, the form is very large, it has to just be a bit on top of the footer.

Comment: Ok, position: relative did the trick, could you explain why?

Comment: @Segi off the top of my head, setting a position of relative, fixed or absolute takes the element out of the page DOM and therefore places it above other elements.

Comment: Of course, thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Like @Sam Mearns said, can you just change the z-index of the other elements.

Also, just add a style tag to the footer on that specific page.

```
<footer class="footer-section sale-footer" style="z-index: 99; position: relative;">
    <div class="footer-wrap">
        <p> ©2017 ... </p>
        <p> ... </p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Can we have the class from your stylesheet of both the footer and the other element? Also, can you include the other elements HTML?

Answer (score 0):

May be original z ndex is applied with a more specific rule. You need to check from Dev tools. Try #pageId .footer-section { z-index: 99999 /* more than original */ }